# IF formula to compare a date with current date and return result

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, compare

I'm looking for a formula which allows me to look at a cell and check if it greater than or equal to today's date and to return a worded result such as "overdue". If it is blank to return another word, or nothing.

I have tried copying the result from the source cell (`O10`) into another cell (`Y10`) and used an if statement but this seems overly laborious - there must be a way to read the information from the source cell? See below. It also returns overdue when the cell is blank :(

```
=IF(O10>Y10,"OVERDUE","NOT DUE")
```

Comment: This isn't off-topic, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/4284627.

Answer (score 18):

You can enter the following formula in the cell where you want to see the `Overdue` or `Not due` result:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(O10),"",IF(O10<TODAY(),"Overdue","Not due"))
```

This formula first tests if the source cell is blank. If it is, then the result cell will be filled with the empty string. If the source is not blank, then the formula tests if the date in the source cell is before the current day. If it is, then the value is set to `Overdue`, otherwise it is set to `Not due`.

Comment: Nice. Just for fun, this will add letting you know if O10 is actually text instead of a number that could be a date, or if the value is invalid. `=IF(ISERROR(O10),"Invalid Value",IF(ISTEXT(O10),"Not a date",IF(ISBLANK(O10),"",IF(O10<TODAY(),"Overdue","Not due"))))`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will cover any possible scenario for what is in O10:

`=IF(ISBLANK(O10),"",IF(O10<TODAY(),IF(TODAY()-O10<>1,CONCATENATE("Due in ",TEXT(TODAY()-O10,"d")," days"),CONCATENATE("Due in ",TEXT(TODAY()-O10,"d")," day")),IF(O10=TODAY(),"Due Today","Overdue")))`

For Dates that are before Today, it will tell you how many days the item is due in. If O10 = Today then it will say "Due Today". Anything past Today and it will read overdue. Lastly, if it is blank, the cell will also appear blank. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

The formula provided by Blake doesn't seem to work for me. For past dates it returns due in xx days and for future dates, it returns overdue. Also, it will only return 15 days overdue, when it could actually be 30, 60 90+.

I created this, which seems to work and provides 'Due in xx days', 'Overdue xx days' and 'Due Today'.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(O10),"",IF(DAYS(TODAY(),O10)<0,CONCATENATE("Due in ",-DAYS(TODAY(),O10)," Days"),IF(DAYS(TODAY(),O10)>0,CONCATENATE("Overdue ",DAYS(TODAY(),O10)," Days"),"Due Today")))
```